# React useEffect non-stop fetching

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm trying to fetch some data from the backend and display those data in a dropdown menu.

```javascript
  const[allGroups, setAllGroups] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect")
    // get all Groups
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/group/getAll")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        let arr = []
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
          arr.push(data[i]["groupName"])
        }
        setAllGroups(arr)
      })
  }, [allGroups])
```

And this is where I generate things

```javascript
<Dropdown.Menu>
  <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">Action</Dropdown.Item>
  {
    allGroups.map((group, i) => {
      return (
        <Dropdown.Item key={i}>{group}</Dropdown.Item> 
      )
    })
  }
</Dropdown.Menu>
```

I noticed the `useEffect` hook was running basically all the time (even if the value of `allGroups` didn't change). I thought `useEffect` only runs when the specified elements on the page rerender. Is there a way to only trigger `useEffect` when `allGroups` change? Thanks!

Comment: wh you are looping with the response

Comment: Which reactjs version you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to only trigger `useEffect` when `allGroups` change?

That's exactly what your code is doing already. However, `allGroups` is changing each time the function is run (since you're calling `setAllGroups` as part of that function).

If you only want the items to be fetched once (after component's first render), remove `allGroups` from the deps array.

If you want to re-fetch the data in response to some user action, define a separate method that can be explicitly called, and then call it appropriately (e.g. when a button is clicked) in addition to calling it within `useEffect` with an empty deps array.

Comment: Ok this is what I'm currently doing so it only renders once when the site first loads. Just out of curiosity, is there a way to make useEffect update the list whenever the content of the list changes?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove allGroups params from useEffect dependencys

this happened because on each render you fetch your data and when fetch success you set new data to all Groups state that make useEffect rerender

```
  const[allGroups, setAllGroups] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
      getAllGroups()
  }, [])


const getAllGroups = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/group/getAll")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        let arr = []
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
          arr.push(data[i]["groupName"])
        }
        setAllGroups(arr)
      })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

by using `allGroups inside the useEffect`  the `useEffect` will be re-render the component as long the `allGroups` change.

you just need to fetch the `APIS` in the first render for the component that will lead you to just use `useEffect with empty dependency like this []`. after getting the `response` just update the `state by using setAllGroups`. then implement what you need on `allGroups`

```
 const[allGroups, setAllGroups] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect")
    // get all Groups
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/group/getAll")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        setAllGroups(data) <= just update the state with the response here.
      })
  }, []) <= you don't need to add **allGroups** here
```

Comment: hey thanks for the response. I actually tried your approach at first and this also made useEffect run constantly (the console.log() keeps printing things)